# Struggling to push view controller on to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with 5 tabs(and a UITabBarController). I have more view controllers which can be shown when user clicks buttons etc. Right now I'm trying to push a view controller in the first tab. When I use the following code, the new view controller completely replaces both the tab bar and the previous view controller so the only view controller that is shown is the new one and there's no way to go back. Here's my code:

```
@objc func openSettingsPage() {
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingsPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings") as! SettingsViewController
self.tabBarController?.show(vc, sender: self)
```

}
I've also tried:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingsPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings") as!      SettingsViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Nothing happens when doing that. trying print(self.navigationcontroller) prints "nil" so apparently it doesn't find a navigation controller even though the view controller I'm writing the code in is embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: You can push the view controller from tab bar controller's selected view controller

Comment: @Mannopson thanks for the suggestion, but I've still got the same problem - the view controller I'm pushing starts to cover the whole screen so I'm unable to go back to my application

Comment: Are you tried my suggestion above? And do not push view controller. Firstly embed in your Setting View Controller to the navigation controller and present modally. Also present the navigation controller instead and not the settings view controller